# interpolation search example with O(logn)

Tags: algorithm, search

Hi I am trying to construct input for which interpolation search would need O(logn) time, and not O(lg log n ) like usually.

By increrasing the "jumps" I was even able to get somethin in O(n) with following data: $[1, 2, 4, 8, ..., 2^{28}, 2^{29}]$ but I can't find something with O(logn).

Comment: can you show us what have you tried so far, a pseudo-code

Comment: Do you want an example where searching for single term requires O(log n) time or searching for any term requires O(log n) time?

Comment: do you have any trouble in implementing binary search?

Comment: Do you mean interpolation search in the sense defined here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search